# Return integer or string instead of None from a JMESPath query

Tags: python, jmespath

Is there a way to return an integer or a string instead of `None`?
I know that I can do an additional check like:

```py
item = {"SX": {"BX": 1}}

value = jmespath.search("SX.BX", item) if jmespath.search("SX.BX", item) else 0
```

but the condition is very long and I would like to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build that logic in your JMESPath query:

```
SX.BX || `0`
```

Given the empty JSON:

```json
{}
```

Would yield you `0`, as you are excepting it.

---

So, you Python code becomes:

```py
value = jmespath.search("SX.BX || `0`", item)
```